# not able to display data in the server side which is sent from frontend

Tags: node.js

i am sending data from reactjs to server. In my server part i am not able to display the data sent from react. when i run the code it's showing undefined in terminal window of server part. but react is sending the data .

```
var value;
server.post('/create',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
  value : (req.body.value)


  console.log( JSON.stringify(value));
;
  res.send(JSON.stringify(value));
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930290/not-able-to-send-the-data-to-server-using-react-and-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Try

value = req.body.value;

colons are not for assign value.